# MapKit JS Select Annotation Programmatically

Tags: mapkit

It's a pretty simple question. In MapKit JS, how can you set an annotation as the selected annotation?

I already have the annotation on the map view and access to the annotation I want to select. I feel like there should be a method similar to what MapKit (not js, just normal) has.

`MKMapView`:

```
func selectAnnotation(_ annotation: MKAnnotation, 
             animated: Bool)
```

Am I just missing it in the MapKit JS docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the annotation's `.selected` property to true. I swear I tried that....

Answer (score 1):

You can set the annotation to be selected by setting the annotation's `.selected` property to `true` or by assigning the object to the `.selectedAnnotation` property of the map instance.

You can unset the selected annotation by setting the annotation's `.selected` property to `false` or by assigning the `null` to the `.selectedAnnotation` property of the map instance.

Whichever method you use, the other value will be automatically updated.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!